# Cannot install Netbeans 8.2 on Ubuntu due to java.awt.AWTError and Assistive Technology not found

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, installation

I have recently installed Netbeans 8.2 on Ubuntu and it has run. But after a while not using it, when I clicked on netbeans shortcut, it just appeared the loadding windows and then it's off, nothing else happened. So I decided to reinstall it.
But now when I'm using Terminal to run the netbeans-8.2-linux.sh file, an "Critical error" box appear and say: 
"An unexpected exception happened in thread main. Exception: java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper"
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtdE6.png)

And then I check my javac version:

```
~$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_181
```

Now I can't install Netbeans, really need your help.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with Kubuntu 18.04 when launching Umlet this morning. It appears to be caused by an unattended security upgrade for the openjdk packages.

The answer by rdrever to this askubuntu SE question fixed the error.

Quoting the fix:

```
This can be done by editing the accessibility.properties file for OpenJDK:
sudo vim /etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties
Comment out the following line:
assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you add a link to askubuntu post you quoted ?